# How to make the simple three square box and connect them?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to make the three square box and simply connect them. 
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Below I present three possibilities

- Using basic boxes: `\parbox`es and `\fbox` (without color) or `\fcolorbox` (with color) nad `\hline`.
- Using [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and chains.
- Drawing the diagram as a tree with [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest).

The code

1. A TikZ-free solution:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}

   \newcommand\MBox[2][2em]{%
    \fbox{\parbox[c][2em][c]{#1}{\centering#2}%
    }%
   }
   \newcommand*{\MRule}{$\vcenter{\hrule width 1cm}$}

   \begin{document}

   \MBox{$g(t)$}\MRule\MBox[4em]{System}\MRule\MBox{$y(t)$}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   With some colors (still no TikZ):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{amsmath}

   \newcommand\MBox[3][2em]{%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#3}{\parbox[c][2em][c]{#1}{\centering#2}%
    }%
   }
   \newcommand*{\MRule}{$\vcenter{\hrule width 1cm}$}

   \begin{document}

   \MBox{$g(t)$}{red!70!black!30}\MRule\MBox[4em]{System}{cyan!50}\MRule\MBox{$y(t)$}{red!70!black!30}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

2. A TikZ solution using chains:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{chains}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[
   mbox/.style={
     draw,
     text width=#1,
     align=center,
     minimum height=3em,
     join
     },
     start chain=going right,
     every join/.style=-
   ]
   \node[mbox=2em,on chain] {$g(t)$};
   \node[mbox=3.5em,on chain] {System};
   \node[mbox=2em,on chain] {$y(t)$};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   A colorful approach:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{chains}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[
   mbox/.style={
     draw,
     text width=#1,
     align=center,
     rounded corners,
     minimum height=3em,
     join,
     line width=0.8pt
     },
     start chain=going right,
     every join/.style=-
   ]
   \node[mbox=2em,on chain,fill=red!70!black!30] {$g(t)$};
   \node[mbox=3.5em,on chain,fill=cyan!50] {System};
   \node[mbox=2em,on chain,fill=red!70!black!30] {$y(t)$};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. As a tree, with `forest`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{forest}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{forest}
   for tree={draw,nodes={align=center},grow=east}
   [$g(t)$,fill=red!60!black!30 [System,fill=cyan!30 [$y(t)$,fill=red!60!black!30 ] ] ]
   \end{forest}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Addition: The rule can also be placed on the math axis: `\newcommand*{\MRule}{$\vcenter{\hrule width 1cm}$}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ah, thanks. I updated the answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina it is possible to make this diagram fancy  and colorful, because I will used it in the beamer

Comment: @MickyK Of course! See my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina facing error illegal parameter umber in definition of \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @MickyK `\test` is not a command in my answer. The error comes from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @MickyK You have to double `#` inside the definition of another macro.

Comment: @MickyK the third option in my updated solution is also a one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw this with TikZ as well. Drawing large block diagrams with TikZ is fairly straightforward, moreso than using LaTeX native structures.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (g) [draw, minimum width = 2cm, minimum height=1.2 cm] {$g(t)$};
        \node (system) [draw, minimum width = 3cm, minimum height=1.2 cm] at ($ (g) + (5cm, 0)$) {System};
        \node (y) [draw, minimum width = 2cm, minimum height=1.2 cm] at ($ (system) + (5cm, 0)$) {$y(t)$};

        \draw [->] (g.east) -- (system.west);
        \draw [->] (system.east) -- (y.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code gives the following output:

[image: simple block diagram]

Answer (score 3):

One line TikZ solution :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
  \tikz\graph[nodes=draw, grow right=14mm] { "$g(t)$" -- "System" -- "$y(t)$"};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: want to make it fancy in one line solution, because I want to use in beamer

Comment: @MickyK no problem : add `nodes={draw,cloud}` (but don't forget `shapes.symbols` library) ;)

Answer (score 2):

A MetaPost solution, for whom it may interest:

```
input boxes
beginfig(1);
  boxjoin(b.w - a.e = (3cm, 0));
  boxit.g(btex $g(t)$ etex);
  boxit.sys(btex System etex);
  boxit.y(btex $y(t)$ etex);
  defaultdx := .75cm;
  defaultdy := .5cm;
  drawboxed(g, sys, y);
  drawarrow g.e -- sys.w; drawarrow sys.e --  y.w;
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,every arrow/.append style=dash
    ,cells={%
        nodes={%
            ,draw
            ,minimum width = 1.45cm % optional if you want squares
            ,minimum height= 1.45cm % optional if you want squares
            %,rounded corners % if you need it fancy...
            %,fill=blue!50 % if you need it fancy...
            }
        }
    ]
g(t) \rar & \text{System} \rar & y(t)
\end{tikzcd}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]