# How can I draw a rectangle train?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a rectangle train with TikZ?[image]

Comment: [How to make the simple three square box and connect them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251776)

Comment: You could use the `chains` library or even just a `\foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use chain like that

**Edit** more elegant with comment of  Torbjørn T.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}% both are needed for the original code in the question

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,>=latex,node distance=0.7cm]
  { [start chain=trunk going right]

     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (rect1) {$G_1$};
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (rect2) {$G_2$};
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (rect3) {$G_3$};
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (rect4) {$G_4$};
     \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] (rect5) {$G_5$};
  }

% the arrows and labels
\draw (rect1) -- (rect2) node[midway,above] {$k_1$};
\draw (rect2) -- (rect3) node[midway,above] {$k_2$};
\draw (rect3) -- (rect4) node[midway,above] {$k_3$};
\draw (rect4) -- (rect5) node[midway,above] {$k_4$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And you obtain [image]

Comment: If I may, I think you're overcomplicating this. Instead of zero `node distance`, set `node=distance=0.7cm` and remove all the `xshift`s. And for the lines/labels, use e.g. `\draw (rect1) -- (rect2) node[midway,above] {$k_1$};` instead of the `+(7mm,0)` stuff.

Comment: Also, part of the point of using a chain is that you can join them very easily so you don't have to do so separately afterwards.