# draw a rectangular train with separate cars in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I found severals topic about train in latex but I never found a solution for my issue. In fact, I need to draw a train which contains severals cars containing several trainsets.

The only code I found was on [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328546/how-can-i-draw-a-rectangle-train). The idea would be to have a shorter line between trainsets of the same car and a longer line between each car.

```
\tikz\graph[nodes=draw, grow right=14mm] { "$1$" -- "$2$"--"$3$"};
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

It is rather straightforward to draw such a train directly in `tikz` and get whatever dimensions you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw [fill=blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (3,2) node[midway]{1} ;
\draw (3,1) -- (3.5,1);
\draw [fill=blue!20] (3.5,0) rectangle (6.5,2) node[midway]{2};
\draw (6.5,1) -- (11,1);
\draw [fill=blue!20] (11,0) rectangle (14,2) node[midway]{1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could just use `\framebox` and `\rule` (again you can adjust the widths as you desire).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{trainnumber}
\setcounter{trainnumber}{1}
\newcommand\train{\framebox[.75cm]{\arabic{trainnumber}}\stepcounter{trainnumber}}
\newcommand\link{\raisebox{.75ex}{\rule{.25cm}{.5pt}}}
\newcommand\connect{\raisebox{.75ex}{\rule{1cm}{.5pt}}\setcounter{trainnumber}{1}}
\begin{document}
\train\link\train\connect\train
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `chains` library. The idea is to use two nested `\foreach` commands (which are basically loop), the outer one for "cars" and the inner one for "trainsets". In the code, `i` iterates over the list of "cars" and `j` iterates over the list of "trainsets" in a "car". Also using the `if` statement, we increase the distance between the last and first "trainsets" of two consecutive "cars".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mbox/.style={
          draw,
          text width=2em,
          align=center,
          minimum height=1.5em,
          join,
          fill=cyan!20
      },
      start chain=going right,
      every join/.style=-,
      node distance=2mm
 ]
\foreach \i in {1,...,2} % i for no of cars
    {
        \foreach \j in {1,...,3} % j for no of trainsets in a car
            {
            \ifnum\j=1
            \begin{scope}[node distance=10mm]
                \node [mbox, on chain] {\j};
            \end{scope}
            \else
            \node [mbox, on chain] {\j};
            \fi
            }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```